# When saving rasters as RDS, the file loses coord ref and the number of rows and columns change. How to fix this?

Tags: raster, r, terra

I need the rasters saved as RDS in order to be able to use a particular pipeline.

First I change the projection of the raster "lu" originally saved as TIF and this the result:

```
> lulonlat
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 25602, 57077, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0001351803, 0.0001351803  (x, y)
extent      : 7.879075, 15.59476, 54.35174, 57.81262  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : spat_Rq45pCnK9WrH2Mh_9528.tif 
name        : C_01 
min value   :    0 
max value   :    1
```

Then I read all the values of the raster into memory and save as RDS (otherwise I get a 1 KB RDS)

```
lulonlat_all <- lulonlat[]

terra::saveRDS(lulonlat_all, file = "C:\\Users\\dir\\lulonlat_all.rds", compress = T)
```

I read the RDS using readRDS and rast

```
test <- readRDS("C:\\Users\\dir\\lulonlat_all.rds")
testrast <- rast(test)

> testrast
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1461285354, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1461285354  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source(s)   : memory
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :     0 
max value   :     1
```

Now there is only one column, there is no coord ref and the extent has changed. How can I fix this?

Comment: A raster of the size you have shown has 1.4 billion cells, which means it will need over 4Gb of RAM, and possibly nearer 10Gb, to just read in one of these as an RDS file to become an in-memory R raster. To do any actual work with it may require multiple lots of 10Gb. Do you have the memory for this? If you really have some weird dependency pipeline on RDS files, then maybe save the TIFF file name to an RDS and have a way to re-read that TIFF into a *non* memory raster further down your pipeline.